# Can't figure out how to use value in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

At '?!?' below is where I don't know how to initiate getting into variable 'recursion' a sample from a normal distribution with mean equal to the x axis value of 'seed' and scale '1.'.

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

seed=tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0. , scale=1.).sample()
recursion=tf.distributions.Normal(loc=seed?!? , scale=1.).sample()
```

Tensorflow 1.10, python3.

Answer (score 0):

It just didn't occur to me to simply pass the tensor variable in and find out what happens. Below is code that works fine, no indexing, like for example 'seed[0]' or 'seed[0:0]' instead of simply 'seed', required:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

seed=tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0. , scale=1.).sample()
recursion=tf.distributions.Normal(loc=seed , scale=1.).sample()
```